# jenkins error while running my pipeline script

Tags: docker, maven, jenkins

please, I am getting this error when I run my jenkins pipeline:

### `#10 39.16 [[1;31mERROR[m] Failed to execute goal [32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war[m [1m(default-war)[m on project [36mvprofile[m: [1;31mError assembling WAR: IOException when zipping WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar: No space left on device[m -> [1m[Help 1][m
#10 39.18 [[1;31mERROR[m]
#10 39.18 [[1;31mERROR[m] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
#10 39.18 [[1;31mERROR[m] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
#10 39.18 [[1;31mERROR[m]
#10 39.18 [[1;31mERROR[m] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
#10 39.18 [[1;31mERROR[m] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
#10 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c cd vprofile-repo && mvn install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

> [build_image 4/4] RUN cd vprofile-repo && mvn install:
> #10 39.16 [[1;34mINFO[m] Total time:  36.386 s
> #10 39.16 [[1;34mINFO[m] Finished at: 2023-03-07T16:08:30Z
> #10 39.16 [[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
> #10 39.16 [[1;31mERROR[m] Failed to execute goal [32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war[m [1m(default-war)[m on project [36mvprofile[m: [1;31mError assembling WAR: IOException when zipping WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar: No space left on device[m -> [1m[Help 1][m
> #10 39.18 [[1;31mERROR[m]
> #10 39.18 [[1;31mERROR[m] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
> #10 39.18 [[1;31mERROR[m] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
> #10 39.18 [[1;31mERROR[m]
> #10 39.18 [[1;31mERROR[m] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> #10 39.18 [[1;31mERROR[m] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

---

### Dockerfile:4

### 2 |     RUN apt update && apt install maven -y
3 |     RUN git clone -b vp-docker https://github.com/imranvisualpath/vprofile-repo.git
4 | >>> RUN cd vprofile-repo && mvn install
5 |
6 |     FROM tomcat:8-jre11

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cd vprofile-repo && mvn install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1`

Please, what can I do?

This is my script

`pipeline {
agent any
tools {
maven "MAVEN3"
jdk "OracleJDK8"
}

```
environment {
    registryCredential = 'ecr:eu-west-2:awscreds'
    appRegistry = "355827780067.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/vprofileappimg"
    vprofileRegistry = "https://355827780067.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com"
}
stages {
  stage('Fetch code'){
    steps {
      git branch: 'docker', url: 'https://github.com/devopshydclub/vprofile-project.git'
    }
  }


  stage('Test'){
    steps {
      sh 'mvn test'
    }
  }

  stage ('CODE ANALYSIS WITH CHECKSTYLE'){
    steps {
        sh 'mvn checkstyle:checkstyle'
    }
    post {
      success {
          echo 'Generated Analysis Result'
          }
      }
    }

  stage('build && SonarQube analysis') {
      environment {
         scannerHome = tool 'sonar4.8'
      }
    steps {
      withSonarQubeEnv('sonar') {
             sh '''${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=vprofile \
               -Dsonar.projectName=vprofile-repo \
               -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 \
               -Dsonar.sources=src/ \
               -Dsonar.java.binaries=target/test-classes/com/visualpathit/account/controllerTest/ \
               -Dsonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports/ \
               -Dsonar.jacoco.reportsPath=target/jacoco.exec \
               -Dsonar.java.checkstyle.reportPaths=target/checkstyle-result.xml'''
      }
    }
  }

  stage("Quality Gate") {
    steps {
      timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
                // Parameter indicates whether to set pipeline to UNSTABLE if Quality Gate fails
                // true = set pipeline to UNSTABLE, false = don't
                waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
      }
    }
  }

  stage('Build App Image') {
    steps {
      script {
        dockerImage = docker.build( appRegistry + ":$BUILD_NUMBER", "./Docker-files/app/multistage/")
      }

    }

  }

  stage('Upload App Image') {
    steps{
      script {
        docker.withRegistry( vprofileRegistry, registryCredential ) {
          dockerImage.push("$BUILD_NUMBER")
          dockerImage.push('latest')
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

}`

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please format the question properly in order to be easier to provide help.
You need to open different questions if you have different inquiries.

Regarding the question #1: from the debug logs provided it is noticeable that the machine does not have more disk space: "No space left on device"
You can clear the workspace, or the old builds. Or increase the available disk space and restart the Jenkins Web Server.\